# Hide Applications and Services in Android?

Tags: android, security, service, hide

Is there any way to hide an application from "Manage applications" and a running service from "Running services" in Android?

Comment: Woah , are you trying to do some evil stuff? ;)

Comment: No I don't want to do some evil stuff :), this is not aimed to be a public apk and it will not distributed, I guess I need to build android for this.

Comment: HI metdos I also want to do same thing what you want.
Have you achieved any success please guide me in this regards

Comment: @Android_Crazy Without building source no and I didn't go that deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not supported, except perhaps via custom firmware.

Comment: In addition, what benevolent reason could anyone have for wanting to do so? I always find it interesting to see all of the comments on here asking how to do possibly-nefarious things.

Answer (score 2):

yes there is. As you may or may not know, rootkit company carrieriq has successfully installed rootkits on all android devices (with permission from carriers), not only are the services hidden, but they are hard to remove even if you know what you are looking for.

the application apparently is imbeded into the kernel.. google "Carrier iq" for more information